# Query wont execute on WITH clause?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have recently been migrating my site to a VPS.

With doing this the query which was working on XAMPP is no longer running on the linux side of things.

The first 2 parts of the query run perfectly so I can see the problem is due to the WITH clause I feel.

Tables in this database are in the sql saved over on 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/718QhKmgPYALAS4Zg94cPx/0

I have tested this on XAMPP mysql and this works correctly.

However it does not work on linux.

The query I am running is

```
SET @DrawID := 3; 
SELECT 120 into @MaxTicketNo FROM draw WHERE ID = @DrawID; 
WITH RECURSIVE TicketNumbers (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM TicketNumbers WHERE n < @MaxTicketNo) SELECT n FROM TicketNumbers WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT TicketNumber FROM transaction WHERE DrawID = @DrawID) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

I am receiving this back when executing the query

```
WITH RECURSIVE TicketNumbers (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM TicketNumbers WHERE n < @MaxTicketNo) 
SELECT n FROM TicketNumbers WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT TicketNumber FROM transaction WHERE DrawID = @DrawID) 
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'RECURSIVE TicketNumbers (n) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT n + 1 FROM TicketNumbe' at line 1
>   "

Comment: Maybe your Linux mysql is below 8?

Comment: Can you check the version of MariaDB you're using and share it with us?

Comment: Thanks guys. My MariaDB version was 5.5. I have now upgraded this to 10.3, along with upgrading to PHP 7+